# Devise restore your password redirection url is wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise

So, first of all, I'm not quite the most knowledgeable with rails or heroku, so this may end up being simpler than I fear. I've been helping a startup (not quite sure what happened, but their dev got sick and now they don't have anyone to maintain/develop for their website). The system is built on rails 4.2.6

Last week, we stumbled on a bad redirection (Server not found). Since there is a staging server as well as the main production system, I went  to check if it was happening there as well.

After confirming that is was, indeed, occurring in both servers, I went to check the email template used in reset_password_instruction.html.slim (this is the email template sent to the users). The url helper (if that's the right name) didn't exist in the list of routes generated by `rake routes`. (you're gonna find  can find similar issues elsewhere, like here: [devise issues](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2848)
and 
I changed the url from `edit_password_url`to `edit_user_password_url`, tested it locally and in the staging server and all went well... 
But it's still redirecting me to an inexistent server in the main site

A little confused, I retraced all the steps to make sure I hadn't done anything wrong, checked the code both in the staging and main servers in heroku and everything was basically the same. The oddest thing, though are the redirection URLs. From my understanding, a page like:

"www.mypage.com" would have a redirect url like "www.mypage.com/users/password/edit/userId" or something similar, but it's redirecting me to this:
"http://mailtracker.allbands.com.br/wf/click?upn=wvr..." (the 3 dots are me omitting the rest of the url.

I've looked everywhere for this mailtracker subdomain, I even added it to the DNS rules, but nothing. In the staging, the url is also a tad funky:
https://u3138184.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click?upn=tF6axPyJ...
despite this, it's working normally, which only adds to my confusion...

I'm suspecting that there is some kind of heroku package building  these urls, but something's getting messed up along the way. the resources used by heroku are: SendGrid, New Relic APM and some database stuff which are most likely irrelevant. I'd like to bet on SendGrid, but I found nothing related to URLs in their dashboard.

routes.br

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: "sessions",
    omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks",
    registrations: "users/registrations"},
    path_names: {sign_in: "sign-in",
    sign_out: "sign-out",
    sign_up: "sign-up"}

devise_scope :user do
    get "set_user_info", to: "users/registrations#set_user_info"
  end
```

`rake routes | grep password`

```
user_password POST /users/password(.:format) devise/passwords#create
new_user_password GET /users/password/new(.:format)devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password GET /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
PATCH /users/password(.:format) devise/passwords#update
PUT /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
```

reset_password_instruction.html.slim

```
= render 'header'
p
  | Someone asked for a link to change your password. YOu can do so with the link below:
p
  = link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `link_to` be `edit_user_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token @token)`? The route you have setup is `edit_user_password`

Comment: tbh, I tried both. I first thought that was the issue (and it's what solved the issue in my staging server). Since that didn't work, I switched it back... Anyways... just tested it again (never hurts to be sure, right?), and it's still the same result (Server not found, same url). thanks anyway